# What is the support of the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+x^2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+x^2}}$ be a function, for $a\in \mathbb{R}^+$ fixed.

I am unsure what the inverse transform of $g$ gives explicitly?
Or at least what is the support of this inverse, since  I'm specially interested to find this support.

I will be very grateful if you could help me

Comment: The FT $\hat f$ is given by a rescaled "modified Bessel function of the second kind" $K_0$ function.  The formula you want is in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1 near the words "for example".

Comment: Thanks @Kimchi, to be honest with you, I knew that is related to Bessel's function, that's why I wrote *explicitly* in the question, but what's I'm really looking for is it's support.. any ideas?

Comment: The support is all of $\mathbb R$.  I wrote what I did because I don't know what scaling conventions your definition of inverse Fourier transform uses.  The formula in the Wikipedia article should let you work out these details yourself.